# how to return number of rows affected in hibernate from unmapped class

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public BigInteger data_size() {
        Session br_session = BrUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        br_session.beginTransaction();
        SQLQuery query = br_session.createSQLQuery("select count(*) from Book");
        return (BigInteger) query.list().get(0);
    }
```

Where Book is a table name not a class name. i managed to achieve it in this way. hope it will be helpfull to some people over there

Comment: This will return the number of rows in that table right?? It wont return the affected rows

Comment: What do you mean by rows affected
"

Comment: Yes you are right @Anoop LL. wanted to share the solution. never got a chance to share on the same page because it was locked already